# add new column to dataframe by referencing name of existing columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe of this form:

```
df <- data.frame(abc = c(1, 0, 3, 2, 0), 
                 foo = c(0, 4, 2, 1, 0),
                 glorx = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2))
```

Here, the column names are strings and the values in the data frame are the number of times I would like to concatenate that string in a new data column.  The new column I'd like to create would be a concatenation across all existing columns, with each column name being repeated according to the data.

For example, I'd like to create this new column and add it to the dataframe.

```
new_col <- c('abc', 'foofoofoofoo', 'abcabcabcfoofoo', 'abcabcfooglorx', 'glorxglorx')
also_acceptable <- c('abc', 'foofoofoofoo', 'abcfooabcfooabc', 'abcfooglorxabc', 'glorxglorx')

df %>% mutate(new_col = new_col, also_acceptable = also_acceptable)
```

The order of concatenation does not matter.  The core problem I have is I don't know how to reference the name of a column by row when constructing a `purrr::map()` or `dplyr::mutate()` function to build a new column.  Thus, I'm not sure how to programatically construct this new column.

(The core application here is combinatorial construction of chemical formulae in case anyone wonders why I would need such a thing.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `Map` and `strrep`:

```
mutate(df, new_col = do.call(paste, c(sep="", Map(strrep, names(df), df))))

#  abc foo glorx         new_col
#1   1   0     0             abc
#2   0   4     0    foofoofoofoo
#3   3   2     0 abcabcabcfoofoo
#4   2   1     1  abcabcfooglorx
#5   0   0     2      glorxglorx
```

Or a simpler version as @thelatemail's comment:

```
df %>% mutate(new_col = do.call(paste0, Map(strrep, names(.), .)))
```

---

`Map` gives a list as follows:

```
Map(strrep, names(df), df) %>% as.tibble()

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#        abc          foo      glorx
#      <chr>        <chr>      <chr>
#1       abc                        
#2           foofoofoofoo           
#3 abcabcabc       foofoo           
#4    abcabc          foo      glorx
#5                        glorxglorx
```

Use `do.call(paste, ...)` to paste strings rowwise.

Comment: Nice, but you can simplify with `paste0` - `do.call(paste0, Map(strrep, names(df), df))`

Comment: @thelatemail That's right. I get `paste0` this time. :)